# Automatically Create Links When Pattern and Numeric Digit Encountered - PHP or SED?

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, sed, pattern-matching

I have many webpages with content that looks like this:

> History.—s. 1, ch. 71-135; s. 19, ch. 73-331; s. 1, ch. 74-384; s. 1,
>   ch. 76-31; s. 1, ch. 79-408; s. 1, ch. 80-343; s. 2, ch. 82-155; s. 1,
>   ch. 82-403; s. 2, ch. 83-187; s. 1, ch. 83-228; s. 1, ch. 84-359; s.
>   24, ch. 85-167; s. 2, ch. 85-337; s. 1, ch. 86-296; s. 2, ch. 88-5; s.
>   5, ch. 88-82; s. 8, ch. 88-196; s. 8, ch. 88-324; s. 60, ch. 88-381;
>   s. 7, ch. 89-3; ss. 1, 18, ch. 91-255; s. 32, ch. 92-78; ss. 1, 11,
>   ch. 93-124; s. 3, ch. 93-246; s. 1, ch. 94-324; s. 895, ch. 95-148; s.
>   1, ch. 95-186; s. 4, ch. 95-333; s. 12, ch. 95-408; s. 3, ch. 96-330;
>   s. 2, ch. 96-413; s. 48, ch. 97-100; s. 97, ch. 97-264; s. 25, ch.
>   97-271; ss. 6, 13, ch. 98-324; s. 5, ch. 99-234; s. 139, ch. 99-248;
>   s. 4, ch. 2000-313; s. 10, ch. 2000-320; s. 2, ch. 2002-78; s. 1, ch.
>   2002-263; s. 1, ch. 2004-379; s. 1, ch. 2005-119; s. 3, ch. 2007-211;
>   s. 29, ch. 2008-111; s. 5, ch. 2008-176; s. 5, ch. 2009-138; s. 10,
>   ch. 2009-206; s. 5, ch. 2010-223.

I want to automatically create links in the text, using either PHP script or sed rewrites to the multiple pages.  I am not very skilled in either of them, I have no thoughts of even how to begin this.

Every time "ch. XXXX-YYY" or "ch. XXXX-YY" is encountered, I want it to create a link on that text that looks like http://www.foo.com/XXXX/YYY.   I do not want it to create the links when there is only two digits (i.e. ch. XX-YYY).

Again, I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: please edit your post to include a small set of sample data (1-3 cases) that cover the range of issues you expect to encounter, and expected output. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/ch\. \([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2,3\}\);/!d;s//\nhttp:\/\/www.foo.com\/\1\/\2\n/;s/[^\n]*\n//;P;D' file
http://www.foo.com/2000/313
http://www.foo.com/2000/320
http://www.foo.com/2002/78
http://www.foo.com/2002/263
http://www.foo.com/2004/379
http://www.foo.com/2005/119
http://www.foo.com/2007/211
http://www.foo.com/2008/111
http://www.foo.com/2008/176
http://www.foo.com/2009/138
http://www.foo.com/2009/206
http://www.foo.com/2010/223
```